# For this parametric equation, I am having some troubles. $x = t^2 − 4$, $y = t + 1$, $−3 ≤ t ≤ 3$

Tags: calculus

Eliminate the parameter to find a Cartesian equation of the curve for 
$−2 ≤ y ≤ 4$. My answer is $\sqrt{(x+4)}-1 =y$. Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: start with $t = y-1$ now substitute into your equation for $x.$  It is a quadratic.  So, what you have is not wrong.  Its just  missing part of the parabola.

Comment: so now I have x = (y-1)^2 -4, then what do I do?

Comment: you are done... you could say $x = y^2 - 2y - 3$

Comment: unfortunately, when i plug that in as an answer in my homework, it says it is incorrect. I am not sure why.

Comment: Is your homework on a learning management system such as Blackboard or is it on a system which comes with your textbook?

Comment: Some systems are better than others at checking for equivalent answers. When I was teaching there were a few occasions where students had a correct answer but the automated homework system marked it wrong. But I  was able to log onto the system and give the student credit. If this is for a class, then your teacher should be able to do this for you. Never be afraid to challenge a seemingly incorrect answer because sometimes they actually are incorrect.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales. This is a nice and encouraging comment.